# As page moderator, cannot embed review

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

What could cause a Moderator on a Facebook business page not to be able to embed reviews of the business?

To sanity check, I created a business page, and left a review of it using another account.  Both the other account and my page admin account were able to access an "Embed" link in the three-dot menu beside the review, right between "Turn on notifications for this post" and "Report post".  However, as a page mod on another existing business page, the "Embed" link is missing.

(I attempted to create a third account to make a Moderator just in case for whatever reason mods cannot embed, but was not able to - Facebook wanted me to confirm with a phone number to create a 3rd account, which I could not do just now.)

I also quickly searched my test page's Settings pages for the text "embed" but the text was not found.